# Get value of vector of struct element based on string

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a struct defined as follows

```
struct a_t
{
    std::string ID;
    std::string Description;
};
```

and a vector on the struct `a_t` defined as follows:

```
std::vector<a_t> aList
```

The contents of `aList` are as follows:

```
ID    Description
=================
one_1  Device 1
two_2  Device 2
three_3 Device 3
....
```

Given a string `one`, I am supposed to search through `aList` to find the Description of that particular element. In this case, I have to get `Device 1` as the output.

How should I go about with this?

Comment: you mean `one_1`??

Comment: No, I mean `one`. I am trying to match a part of the string.

Comment: Can it have multiple description?? or is there `one_1, one_2 ...` IDs present???

Comment: go through the vector with iterator, and do the match work.

Comment: Do you really want to store the ID as a string? Why not using an int? Did you consider vector<string>, with access aList[ID] in the case that ID is indeed integral? Or, if you need ID to be a string, did you consider map<string,string>? In the last case, and if you need to match the beginning of the key string only, maybe aList.lower_bound("one") would be suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::find_if` of `<algorithm>`

```
a_t item;
auto pred = [](const a_t & item) {
    int p = -1;
    p= item.ID.find("one");
    return p >= 0;
};
std::vector<a_t>::iterator pos=std::find_if(std::begin(aList), std::end(aList), pred);
std::cout <<"\nResult:" <<pos->Description;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for(std::vector<a_t>::iterator it = aList.begin(); it != aList.end(); ++it) {
    if ((*it).ID.find("one") != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << (*it).Description<< '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Didn't test the code first time. I was just giving the idea. Anyway, updated the code.